# Probability in a given distribution

Tags: distributions

I have the following distribution:

```
a=0.215775;
b=1.76885;
c=2.28023;

edistT=StudentTDistribution[a,b,c]
```

I would like to calculate, numerically, the value, `pr` above which the probability drops to, let us say, 10%. I tried the following:

```
NSolve[NProbability[x >= pr, x \[Distributed] edistT] == 0.1, pr]
```

But I only get a series of errors.

Comment: THe function `Quantile`gives what you want. E.g.: `Quantile[edistT, 0.9]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `InverseCDF` is for:

```
pr = InverseCDF[edistT, 1 - 0.1];
```

> 3.3779

Check:

```
NProbability[x >= pr, x \[Distributed] edistT]
CDF[edistT, pr]
```

> 0.1

> 0.9

Comment: This is a good way to solve the problem - but it doesn't explain why the original formulation doesn't work.

Comment: @mikado That's because `NProbability[x >= pr, x \[Distributed] edistT]` is not a closed-form formula in `pr`, so `NSolve` doesn't really know what to do with it. If you use `Probability` with `NSolve` or `FindRoot` with `NProbability`, it will work fine. Still, it's less efficient than using `InverseCDF`.